# Data stops pushing to bigquery

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to load data from postgresql db to bigquery by using fetch with cursor and have the issue that it wouldn't push enough data to BQ, it only inserted the first batch (1000 rows) and gave no error in log as well.

If this code is run on my laptop, it will work well. But, it's a different story if I bring it to GCP Composer.

The data only contains 8 columns, 4 columns with int value range from 1 to 20M (like user_id), 2 columns contain string (like user_name, hash), 2 columns contain date value (created_date, dwh_created_date). Total row will be ~100k.

Below is my code. I already tried to input the sleep time for each fetch, cuz I thought that it needs time for processing also maybe Google would have a gap time for API requesting. The data frame contains enough data, so I suspected there should be something else.

```
with cursor:
    cursor.execute(sql_query)
    while True:
        rows = cursor.fetchmany(1000)
        if not rows:
            break
        logger.info(f"rows :{len(rows)}")
        column_names = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]
        logger.info(f"Column name: {column_names}")
        df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=column_names)
        df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
        if schema_dict is not None and selected_column is not None:
            df = df[selected_column]
            df = convert_pandas_datatype(df, schema_dict)
        client.load_table_from_dataframe(
            df,
            table_id,
            job_config=job_config
        )
        # from time import sleep
        # sleep(5)
        # print("sleeping............")
conn.close()
```

So how can I input enough data to BigQuery..

Comment: Can you modify `client.load_table_from_dataframe( df,table_id,job_config=job_config )`   to  `client.load_table_from_dataframe( df,table_id,job_config=job_config ).result()`. Let me know if this solved your issue or not.

Comment: thank @kiranmathew, now it showed up new error. Now i can know that it's related to the data fetched from postgresql source. Which give more columns than the schema i inputted. After checking the fetched result, the 2nd fetch gave only index. I will have to check about that...

Comment: the issue has been resolved bro, thank you for your help. I'd figured out last night. Let me sum up this.

Firstly, I missed the job_config.result() which was already in Google API Document. Hence, it didn't finish its job.
Secondly, as long as I used the `map` function, I didn't assign the value into a variable, hence the later iteration of the loop after the first one will give no value in `column_names` and `column_names`, that would result in no data in data frame due to no columns name

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer since it partially helped to resolve your issue please consider  upvoting it.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [google cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigquery/latest/index.html) to wait for a job to complete you need to use the result() function.The job.result() function will wait for the job to complete. Example:`rows = query_job.result()` . You can edit your code as below:

```
with cursor:
    cursor.execute(sql_query)
    while True:
        rows = cursor.fetchmany(1000)
        if not rows:
            break
        logger.info(f"rows :{len(rows)}")
        column_names = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]
        logger.info(f"Column name: {column_names}")
        df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=column_names)
        df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
        if schema_dict is not None and selected_column is not None:
            df = df[selected_column]
            df = convert_pandas_datatype(df, schema_dict)
       job= client.load_table_from_dataframe(
            df,
            table_id,
            job_config=job_config
        )
       job.result()
       
conn.close()
```

Never use the `sleep()` function unnecessarily because this method suspends the execution of the current thread for a given number of seconds. This will create unnecessary problems. For more information, you can follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154899/the-disadvantages-of-using-sleep)

Comment: Thank you so much @kiran-mathew, it's so nice cuz this will help me much in understanding the code. Also yeah, I abused the `sleep()` too much, that's also a nice notice from your help. Thanks again and regards,